# [New maven project in eclipse on MacOS]How to solve "Could not resolve archetype..."?

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven

I am working on MacOS 10.14.6 with:

- java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
- Apache Maven 3.6.2
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)

When I tried to open a new maven project, the following error happened:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

I have tried the following:

- set proxy in settings.xml and place it in .m2 folder

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>****</username>
      <password>****</password>
      <host>proxy****</host>
      <port>**</port>
      <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

- set proxy in network connections in eclipse
- configure the settings.xml paths of global and user settings in eclipse as the settings.xml in the installed folder
- delete .m2 folder and restart eclipse
- add remote archetype catalog with the path
  `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml`

May I have your kind help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by adding the mirror content in the settings.xml. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html